# Error While Inserting Data to Database from Java Program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to develop a inventory management system as part of my mini project.

While I try to Insert a data to my Bill_Master Database it returning an error

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
       bqty=Integer.parseInt(iqty.getText());
       bamount=Float.parseFloat(famnt.getText());
       bdsc=Integer.parseInt(dsc.getText());
        bnet=Float.parseFloat(netamnt.getText());
         billid=Integer.parseInt(billn.getText());
         code=Integer.parseInt(icode.getText());
         bqty=Integer.parseInt(iqty.getText());
         rate=getRate(code);
         iamount=rate*bqty;
         amt.setText(Float.toString(iamount)); 
         total=total+iamount;


       try 
       {
           billdetailid++;  
     stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Bill_Master values('"+billid+"','"+date+"','"+cname+"','"+total+"','"+bdsc+"','"+total+"','"+uid+"')");//Error Causing Line.
```

Values are
(1,'27-oct-2013','n/a',900.00,0.0,900.00,'Desk')

Table Structure

1. Bill_Id (Primary  Key INT ):-Stores Bill Number
2. Bill_Date (Date): Stores Date Of Bill
3. Customer_Name ( VARCHAR(50)): Customer Name
4. Total_amt (NUMBER(6)) :Total Bill Amount
5. Cash_Disc (Number(2)):Discount
6. Grand_Total(Number(6)):Grand Total
7. UID(VARCHAR(10)) Stores Who Generated the bill.(EMPLOYEE  ID)
   Connection Type :ODBC

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact problem. The reason was I am trying to insert the Label instead of the text in the label.
correct statement is

`stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Bill_Master values('"+billid+"','"+date.getText()+"','"+cname.getText()+"','"+total+"','"+bdsc+"','"+total+"','"+uid+"')");`

Answer (score 1):

You are putting single quotes around each of your values including bill_Id which is defined as an int. the SQL database is reading this as a string and complaining. Also (as was already pointed out) PreparedStatements make this a lot easier and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Bill_Master values('"+billid+"',to_date('"+date+"', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),'"+cname+"','"+total+"','"+bdsc+"','"+total+"','"+uid+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that is one horrible way of writing SQL queries in java !!!

I am guessing you have just started learning. Please check out [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Data Type related bugs will become easier to debug.

Also that is not the way you write continuous string appends. Check out StringBuilder and String Buffer